# Get root url of the site in PHP

Tags: php

Consider my project directory structure as follows,

```
-public_html
  -projects
    -folder1
      index.php \\code is written here
    +folder2
  +downloads
```

I am trying to get the root directory through `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, but it seems the returned string is not in the form I expect.

My directory inside my website is (basically in) `public_html/projects/folder1`. Using document root, the returned string is as follows when implemented on a website,
`/home/site_name/public_html` which is not going to work if the link is to be shared, cause I am using it to store the file in a directory. So, I want something like it should return, `www.site_name.com/downloads`

The `__DIR__` is giving the whole document path from where it is called(`folder1/index.php`), but I want to get into the main folder ( `public_html/downloads` ), not in the same folder as the index file is.

Are there any other php functions that can help to reach the **downloads folder** in public_html and which can be accessed like, www.sitename.com/downloads/...

Comment: Look through the array and choose for yourself what works best for you: `echo '<pre>' . print_r($_SERVER) . '</pre>';`

Comment: @JackNicholson A couple years old but you should do `echo '<pre>' . print_r($_SERVER,true)  . '</pre>';  As adding the true to the print_r function will allow it to print as a string instead as an object.

Comment: @DawsonIrvine Ah yes that is correct! I probably typed it out in the commend rather than copy and paste

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To return the folder of current php file, use this script.

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; //returns the current URL
$parts = explode('/',$url);
$dir = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($parts) - 1; $i++) {
 $dir .= $parts[$i] . "/";
}
echo $dir;
```

Comment: that looks awefully unclean :-/

Comment: Martin, Honestly, I have seen this type of code on many sites, but as a beginner, this code is the only one that I am able to understand completely. Thanks @linkan for explaining me the explode function very well. :)

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` to get the root URL of the site. You can use this to get a URL to your downloads folder.

```
$downloads_url = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/downloads/';
```

Comment: this worked, but now if I have to make a dir in server using this at beginning, will it work? Like `$target_dir = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']\downloads\file` . Now if I move the uploaded file to this directory using `move_uploaded_file(...)` ?

Answer (score 0):

constants.php:

```
define('PROTOCOL',(!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on')) ? 'https://' : 'http://',true);
define('DOMAIN',$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define('ROOT_URL', preg_replace("/\/$/",'',PROTOCOL.DOMAIN.str_replace(array('\\',"index.php","index.html"), '', dirname(htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], ENT_QUOTES))),1).'/',true);// Remove backslashes for Windows compatibility
```

Then, in the the index of the project `use` it